# Viso2_ros without camera_info

Tags: ros, image-raw, camera-info, viso2, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I'm trying to compute visual odometry using a stream of images (left and rigth) from a server
These images come without camera_info, but i have a calibration file

> 

cam0:
T_cam_imu:

- [0.01486554298177506, 0.9995572490081733, -0.025774436697406162, 0.06522290953548025]
- [-0.9998809296982875, 0.014967213324687367, 0.003756188357965682, -0.020706385492743767]
- [0.004140296794218436, 0.025715529947969162, 0.999660727177951, -0.008054602460032234]
- [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
  cam_overlaps: [1]
  camera_model: pinhole
  distortion_coeffs: [-0.28340811217029355, 0.07395907389290132, 0.00019359502856909603,
  1.7618711454538528e-05]
  distortion_model: radtan
  intrinsics: [458.6548807207614, 457.2966964634893, 367.2158039615726, 248.37534060980727]
  resolution: [752, 480]
  rostopic: /cam0/image_raw
  cam1:
  T_cam_imu:
- [0.012555267089114197, 0.9995987811512158, -0.025389800891792866, -0.04490198068250312]
- [-0.9997550997230579, 0.013011905181515238, 0.017900583825283624, -0.02056977125889907]
- [0.018223771455430235, 0.025158836311545446, 0.999517347077773, -0.008638135126028613]
- [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
  T_cn_cnm1:
- [0.9999972564778362, 0.002312067192393073, 0.00037600810233414045, -0.11007380812712879]
- [-0.0023171357232427163, 0.9998980485068706, 0.014089835846681338, 0.0003991215470570765]
- [-0.00034339312053936386, -0.014090668452710595, 0.9999006626379018, -0.0008537025033537094]
- [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
  cam_overlaps: [0]
  camera_model: pinhole
  distortion_coeffs: [-0.283683654496499, 0.07451284309294819, -0.00010473894909809367,
  -3.555907002742513e-05]
  distortion_model: radtan
  intrinsics: [457.5874266035361, 456.13442556023665, 379.9994465203525, 255.2381853862733]
  resolution: [752, 480]
  rostopic: /cam1/image_raw

Well, i know that i need to rectify the images (before send everything to viso2) with stereo_image_proc, but if i don't have the camera_info stream i can't do it.
I just have the image_raw pair, nothing else.
Do you have any suggests???
thanka a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196470/viso2_ros-without-camera_info/) by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dottant,

for these cases we use a python script to publish the image files into the ros ecosystem using a camera info YAML file with the calibration.

The script is available inside our package [srv_tools](https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/), and it is [this one](https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/blob/indigo/bag_tools/scripts/bag_tools/image_sequence_publisher.py).

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0